# Get error x509 in release job in my local gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, release, x509, cicd

I am running a local gitlab server with self-signed certificate, My pipline builds my application and create a release but I have x509 I tried the workaround mentionned on gitlab documenation but it doesn't work. Everything works fine when tested in gitlab.com

To summerize first I build my application to generate a war file as an artifact, then the artifact is uploaded using gitlab API to generate URL and file path after that release job add tags and generate the release page

my gitlab-ci.yaml

```
---
variables:
  PACKAGE_VERSION: "V7"
  GENERIC_WAR: "mypackage-${PACKAGE_VERSION}.war"
  PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL: "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${PACKAGE_VERSION}"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      when: always
      variables:
        SERVER: "${PROD_SERVER}"

    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
      when: always
      variables:
        SERVER: "${TEST_SERVER}"

    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "feature/release"
      when: always
      variables:
        SERVER: "${TEST_SERVER}"
stages:
  - build
  - upload
  - prepare
  - release
  - deploy

build-application:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.8.4-jdk-8
  script:
    - mvn clean package -U -DskipTests=true
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2h
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/*.war

upload:
  stage: upload
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  needs:
    - job: build-application
      artifacts: true
  # rules:
  #   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  script:
    - |
      curl -k --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file target/*.war "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/${GENERIC_WAR}"

prepare_job:
  stage: prepare
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "feature/release"
  script:
    - echo "EXTRA_DESCRIPTION=some message" >> variables.env # Generate the EXTRA_DESCRIPTION and TAG environment variables
    - echo "TAG=v$(cat VERSION)" >> variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env

release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: prepare_job
      artifacts: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "feature/release"
  before_script:
    - apk --no-cache add openssl ca-certificates
    - mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
    - openssl s_client -connect ${CI_SERVER_HOST}:${CI_SERVER_PORT} -servername ${CI_SERVER_HOST} -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -e '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/!d' | tee "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/${CI_SERVER_HOST}.crt" >/dev/null
    - update-ca-certificates
  script:
    - echo 'running release_job for $TAG'
  release:
    name: "Release $TAG"
    description: "Created using the release-cli $EXTRA_DESCRIPTION"
    tag_name: "$TAG"
    ref: "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    assets:
      links:
        - name: "{$GENERIC_WAR}"
          url: "${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}"
          filepath: "/${GENERIC_WAR}"
```

Release job execution

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.2 (e91107dd)
  on Shared-Docker mdaS6_cA
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest ...
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:c2d3a3c3b9ad5ef63478b6a6b757632dd7994d50e603ec69999de6b541e1dca8 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli@sha256:68e201226e1e76cb7edd327c89eb2d5d1a1d2b0fd4a6ea5126e24184d9aa4ffc ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-mdas6ca-project-32-concurrent-0 via Docker-Server1...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/Saiida/backend-endarh/.git/
Checking out 7735e9ea as feature/release...
Removing target/
Removing variables.env
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
Using docker image sha256:c2d3a3c3b9ad5ef63478b6a6b757632dd7994d50e603ec69999de6b541e1dca8 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli@sha256:68e201226e1e76cb7edd327c89eb2d5d1a1d2b0fd4a6ea5126e24184d9aa4ffc ...
$ apk --no-cache add openssl ca-certificates
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r5)
(2/2) Installing openssl (1.1.1l-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r6.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r5.trigger
OK: 7 MiB in 16 packages
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
$ openssl s_client -connect ${CI_SERVER_HOST}:${CI_SERVER_PORT} -servername ${CI_SERVER_HOST} -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -e '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/!d' | tee "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/${CI_SERVER_HOST}.crt" >/dev/null
$ update-ca-certificates
Warning! Cannot copy to bundle: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: ca-cert-extra.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
$ echo 'running release_job for $TAG'
running release_job for $TAG
Executing "step_release" stage of the job script
00:01
$ release-cli create --name "Release $TAG" --description "Created using the release-cli $EXTRA_DESCRIPTION" --tag-name "$TAG" --ref "$CI_COMMIT_SHA" --assets-link "{\"url\":\"${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}\",\"name\":\"{$GENERIC_WAR}\",\"filepath\":\"/${GENERIC_WAR}\"}"
time="2021-12-23T08:47:48Z" level=info msg="Creating Release..." cli=release-cli command=create name="Release v" project-id=32 ref=7735e9ea9422e20b09cae2072c692843b118423a server-url="https://gitlab.endatamweel.tn" tag-name=v version=0.10.0
time="2021-12-23T08:47:48Z" level=fatal msg="run app" cli=release-cli error="failed to create release: failed to do request: Post \"https://gitlab.endatamweel.tn/api/v4/projects/32/releases\": x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0" version=0.10.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it work by replacing the yaml format of the release job with the release-cli command and arguments and set --insecure-https option not optimised for production of course

```
release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: prepare_job
      artifacts: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never # Do not run this job when a tag is created manually
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "feature/release" # Run this job when commits are pushed or merged to the default branch
  script:
    - |
      release-cli --insecure-https=true create --name "Release $TAG" --tag-name $TAG --ref $CI_COMMIT_SHA \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"${GENERIC_WAR}\",\"url\":\"${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/${GENERIC_WAR}\", \"link_type\":\"package\"}"
```